# Could any on tell why am I getting following error when I am trying to add float number in the map even though my float is inherited from Number

Tags: java

Could any on tell why am I getting following error when I am trying to add Float in the map  which I am trying to use with bounded wild card?

**The error I'm getting is:**

The method `put(String, Class<? extends Number>)` in the type `Map<String,Class<? extends Number>>` is not applicable for the arguments `(String, Float)`

**And here is my code:**

```
public final static Map<String, Class<? extends Number>> SECTION_DATA = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends Number>>();

static
{
    SECTION_DATA.put("test", new Float(1));
}
```

Comment: Please format this better.

Comment: Don't you need a comma to separate arguments? `"test", new Float(1)`? Maybe this is only a error display issue. It would be better if you posted the code.

Comment: Certainly looks like missing comma after `"test"`. Though I would have hoped for a more informative error message in that case.

Comment: @user2006171 You don't have to be rude, they're just saying you to improve the formatting of your question for keeping SO useful.

Comment: appologies if that sounds rude, I am deleting that

Answer (score 4):

The second argument is of type `Class`, and `Float` is not a subclass of `Class`.

It sounds like you're looking for

```
public final static Map<String, Number> SECTION_DATA = new HashMap<String, Number>();
```

This map will accept values of any class that subclasses `Number`.

Comment: Yes it would but I am trying to use bounded wild card type o any other as by description it says will store either Number or sub type of Number like Integer, Float. This is an example of bounded wildcards in Generics

Comment: @user2006171: NPE is describing how to do exactly that correctly.  `? extends Number` means that you can only insert into the map elements of some unknown type of `Number`, which in practice means nothing.

Comment: Yes I completely understand NPE point and I really appreciate everyonce quick responses but I am currently trying to learn this bounded wildcard generics and following some forum say legal but it gives me above mentioned compile error any thing you see below is a copy paste from there:
Set<? extends Number> setOfAllSubTypeOfNumber = new HashSet<Integer>(); //legal - Integer extends Number
setOfAllSubTypeOfNumber = new HashSet<Float>(); //legal - because Float extends Number"

Comment: This is because you could store any Number in setOfAllSubtypeOfNumber, hence a Set where you can only store Integers is not assignment compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a `Float` to a map that has `Class` values, because although `Float`is a class, it is not subclass of `Class`.

Comment: It is sub class of Number and it should allow
Lets say i have a class emp{getName();} and child class class manager extends emp{getManager(){}}.... now my map<String, <? extends emp>> and i want this map to allow me to put object of manager class which is a child class of emp

Comment: Number is not but Float is a child of Number and since I am trying to use "bounded wild card" so don't you think it should let me add as Float is extended class of Number class

Comment: @user2006171 First and foremost, according to your code, it must be a subclass of **Class** (since you have Map<String,**Class**<...>>), before the validity of the type argument can even be verified. But neither Number nor Float are subclasses of **Class**